# How can we make sure that we can just create one instance of a class?

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, instance

This was an interview question. The interviewer presented me a class Person and another Class Community. He wanted to know what can we do to make sure that within the Class Community, the instance of the Class Person can be called once.

My approach was to define a boolean flag as a Global variable and to check in the constructor of Class Person if the flag value was false, then it will create the instance or else return error. This flag value is changed to true with the creation of the first instance of Class Person.He did not seem very satisfied with the answer.

I understand that this may be not the right way of doing this. Question is, is there a way to do so using Class definition,or a specific type of class?

Comment: He was probably hoping you'd answer by explainin the Singleton pattern.

Comment: I think the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) if what you are looking for.

Comment: Just one more question, was my approach not a feasible solution to the answer?

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta As we have well define design patterns so no need to worry about  feasible solution. Just follow the design and focus on business logic.

Comment: Interviewer question was just to create one object for this class person i.e. work must be done by creating a single object only. Think about it.

Comment: The title of your question is clear, but i don't understand the first paragraph. Do you really want only a single Person instance  ? or a person should be present only one in a community  ?

Comment: @gontard Apologies for the confusion, the interviewer asked to provide a solution where the Class Person can be instantiated only once in the Class Community.

Comment: @SushimMukulDutta so i think the `Set` based answer is the good one.

Comment: @gontard Cracked it, thanks all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not really sur about all the Singleton proposition.

I would have answered the same. But the real question seems to be "How to make the person unique within a community" which is different from "How to make sur we can instanciate Person class once for all".

In that case, I would have done something really different.

I would declare a Set of Person within Community and override Person's equals method.

Then, within a community, the Person would have been unique but Person class could still be instanciated for other Community instances.

```
public class Person{
   ...
    public Boolean equals(Object o){
       Person p = (Person) o;
       //you own equals logic
       return isEqual;
    }
    ...
}


public class Community{
    ...
    private Set<Person>;
    ...
}
```

Comment: i understand the question interviewer in this way too. And a `Set` if the approach i would use.

Comment: Yep, I think the title is missleading.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Java).

```
public class Singleton {
    // Private constructor. Prevents instantiation from other classes.
    private Singleton() { }

    private static class SingletonHolder {
            private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
            return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Or create your class as an `enum` type, making it a true singleton:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    public void execute (String arg) {
        // Perform operation here 
     }
}
```

Comment: A private class that just "holds" the instance? Why do you need a separate class for that?

Comment: @Tom It's one of the many lazy-loading tricks. The enum approach is the preferred way these days.

Comment: @Tom: You could also create the instance in a static block.

Comment: @CamCecil of in the `getInstance()` method, which would make more sense to me (imo it's more readable).

Comment: @Tom I wasn't either, except mentioning that the preferred way (instead of using holder classes or other lazy-loading tricks) is the enum method.